# Can DFA regex engines handle atomic groups?

Tags: regex, dfa

According to [this page](http://useless-factor.blogspot.de/2008/05/regexp-research.html) (and some others), DFA regex engines can deal with capturing groups rather well. I'm curious about atomic groups (or possessive quantifiers), as I recently used them a lot and can't imagine how this could be done.

---

I disagree with the fist part of the answer:

> A DFA does not need to deal with constructs like atomic grouping.... Atomic Grouping is a way to help the engine finish a match, that would otherwise cause endless backtracking

Atomic groups are important not only for speed of NFA engines, but they also allow to write simpler and less error-prone regexes. Let's say I needed to find all C-style multiline comments in a program. The exact regex would be something like:

- start with the literal `/*`
- eat anything of the following

  - any char except `*`
  - a `*` followed by anything but `/`
- repeat this as much as possible
- end with the literal `*/`

This sounds a bit complicated, the regex

```
/\* ( [^*] | \*[^/] )+ \*/
```

is complicated and wrong (it doesn't handle `/* foo **/` correctly). Using a reluctant (lazy) quantifier is better

```
/\* .*? \*/
```

but also wrong as it can eat the whole line

```
/* foo */ @#$!!**@#$ /* bar */
```

when backtracking due to a later sub-expression failing on the garbage occurs. Putting the above in an atomic group solves the problem nicely:

```
(?> /\* .*? \*/ )
```

This works always (I hope) and is as fast as possible (for NFA). So I wonder if a DFA engine could somehow handle it.

Comment: please re-read: "is a way to help the engine finish a match" does not mean "speed up" - it is kind of a workaround for the backtracking issues a NFA brings. As a DFA does not backtrack, those kind of issues don't occur, try matching a string like "=XX================" against /X(.+)+X/ with a traditional NFA as well as with a DFA and feel the difference: a DFA just does not care about the way the regex is written, thus atomic grouping simply CAN NOT affect a DFA

Comment: @DesertEagle: But atomic grouping does effect if the regex match, so it must effect *any* engine. Consider `(?>.*)a` not matching `a` or `(?>".*?"|\s+)+` not matching `"foo" garbage "bar"`. In both cases making the group non-atomic leads to a match.

Comment: it only affects a NFA, since a NFA has a COMPLETELY different way of searching! NFAs work along the regex, shifting the target string back and forth, keeping track of untried positions (atomic grouping throws away part of those untried alternatives). In contrast, the DFA moves along the target string, checking current positions in the string against the regex and tracks all current possible matches in parallel, so there are no states to discard...

Comment: So you're saying that they can't handle it, right? I agree with you saying that the machines work very differently, but that's not my point. An NFA has also nothing like a [defined order](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/leftmost_longest_rule.html), so capturing groups make no sense; yet there's a way (possibly including running a DFA). And I'm asking the same thing about atomics.

Answer (score 1):

A DFA does not need to deal with constructs like atomic grouping. A DFA is "text directed", unlike the NFA, which is "regex directed", in other words:
Atomic Grouping is a way to help the engine finish a match, that would otherwise cause endless backtracking, as the (NFA) engine tries every permutation possible to find a match at a position, no match is even possible.

Atomic grouping, simply said, throws away backtracking positions. Since a DFA does not backtrack (the text to be matched is checked against the regex, not the regex against the text like a NFA - the DFA opens a branch for each decision), throwing away something that is not there is pointless.

I suggest J.F.Friedl's Mastering Regular Expressions [(Google Books)](http://books.google.at/books?id=NYEX-Q9evKoC&pg=PA145&lpg=PA145&dq=types%20of%20regex%20engines&source=bl&ots=qoq1qVNw9z&sig=IGw6KvXt1_2QN0ngg4smUIxkhA0&hl=en&ei=fvu-TPekEIO8lQewj83mBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=types%20of%20regex%20engines&f=false), he explains the general idea of a DFA:

> DFA Engine: Text-Directed
>
> Contrast the regex-directed NFA engine with an engine that, while
> scanning the string, keeps track of all matches “currently in the
> works.” In the tonight example, the moment the engine hits t, it adds
> a potential match to its list of those currently in progress:
>
> [...]
>
> Each subsequent character scanned updates the list of possible
> matches. After a few more characters are matched, the situation
> becomes
>
> [...]
>
> with two possible matches in the works (and one alternative, knight,
> ruled out). With the g that follows, only the third alternative
> remains viable. Once the h and t are scanned as well, the engine
> realizes it has a complete match and can return success.
>
> I call this “text-directed” matching because each character scanned
> from the text controls the engine. As in the example, a partial match
> might be the start of any number of different, yet possible, matches.
> Matches that are no longer viable are pruned as subsequent characters
> are scanned. There are even situations where a “partial match in
> progress” is also a full match. If the regex were ⌈to(…)?⌋, for
> example, the parenthesized expression becomes optional, but it’s still
> greedy, so it’s always attempted. All the time that a partial match is
> in progress inside those parentheses, a full match (of 'to') is
> already confirmed and in reserve in case the longer matches don’t pan
> out.

(Source: http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/regular-expressions/0596528124/regex-directed-versus-text-directed/i87)

Concerning capturing groups and DFAs: as far as I was able to understand from your link,  these approaches are not pure DFA engines but hybrids of DFA and NFA.